# Nested $.getJSON, calls not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, getjson

```
    function dispatchVehicle(){
        if(!chickAll()){
            return false;
        }
        var action = window.url + '?&method=dispatchVehicles'
                + "&conLclFlag=" + conLclFlag
                + "&containerId=" + containerId 
                + "&vehicleNameFlag=1"
                + "&t=" + (new Date()).getTime();

        jQuery.getJSON(action, $('#vehicleForm').serialize(), function(data) {
            if(data.flag){
                if (window.confirm(data.message)) {
                    alert(1);
                    var action1 =  window.url + '?&method=dispatchVehicles'
                        + "&conLclFlag=" + conLclFlag
                        + "&containerId=" + containerId 
                        + "&vehicleNameFlag=2"
                        + "&t=" + (new Date()).getTime();
                    alert(2);
                    jQuery.getJSON(action1, $('#vehicleForm').serialize(), function(data1) {
                    alert(3);
                    if(!data1.flag){
                        alert(data1.message);
                    }
                    if (data1.succ) {
                        window.parent.location.reload();
                        window.parent.ClosePop();
                    }
                    });
                }
            }
            if (data.succ) {
                window.parent.location.reload();
                window.parent.ClosePop();
            }
        });
    }
```

I need to perform two ajax calls through jQuery's getJSon function.

The thing is that, once one of the calls is performed and data.flag is true, call the second getJSon function (because I need the result of the first call as a condition in the second call).
But when the function runs, the code "alert(3)" can not be executed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In stead of nesting it, try setting up an array of callbacks.

Comment: what is your action1's string . can you post it , any javascript errors in frebug

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `.getJSON()` should nest OK.

You could try my version of your code below though to be honest, all I have done is to rearrange things for better efficiency, plus greater assurance that the inner `.getJSON()` is the same as the outer, with the required variation. The nesting and structure is otherwise identical.

javascript:

```
function dispatchVehicle(){
    if(!chickAll()){
        return false;
    }
    var action = window.url + '?' + $('#vehicleForm').serialize();//reusable string
    var dataObj = {//reusable object
        method: 'dispatchVehicles',
        conLclFlag: conLclFlag,
        containerId: containerId, 
        vehicleNameFlag: 1,
        t: (new Date()).getTime()
    };

    $.getJSON(action, dataObj, function(data) {
        if(data.flag){
            if (window.confirm(data.message)) {
                alert(1);
                //now reuse action and dataObj with a couple of changed properties
                dataObj.vehicleNameFlag = 2;
                dataObj.t = (new Date()).getTime();
                alert(2);
                $.getJSON(action, dataObj, function(data1) {
                    alert(3);
                    if(!data1.flag){
                        alert(data1.message);
                    }
                    if (data1.succ) {
                        window.parent.ClosePop();
                        window.parent.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        if (data.succ) {
            window.parent.location.reload();
            window.parent.ClosePop();
        }
    });
}
```